# How to integrate LUIS service with bot?

Tags: c#, botframework, cortana

I am developing a CORTANA app with LUIS, the Root dialog is consuming the LUIS and based on user intention I am redirecting him to another dialog but I have observed that after execution of Root dialog constructor and exception occurs while I have another dialog without LUIS (i.e. InsightsDialog commented below) that is working fine.

Following code is redirecting to Root Dialog from MessagesController:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
                   //await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.InsightsDialog());
            }
            else
            {
                await HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
```

Root Dialog Code:

```
[Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {
        InsightsDialog customerInsightsDialog = null;
        public RootDialog() : base(new LuisService(Utility.GetLUISAttributesFromConfig()))
        {
            customerInsightsDialog = new InsightsDialog();
        }
        public static LuisModelAttribute GetLUISAttributesFromConfig()
        {
                return new LuisModelAttribute(Constants.RootDialogLuisModelId, Constants.RootDialogLuisSubscriptionKey);
        }

       #region Intents
        [LuisIntent("")]
        [LuisIntent("None")]
        public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
                string userInput = result.Query;
                context.Call(customerInsightsDialog, ResumeAfterInsightsDialog);
        }

        [LuisIntent("Greetings")]
        public async Task Greetings(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
                string userInput = result.Query;
                context.Call(customerInsightsDialog, ResumeAfterInsightsDialog);
        }

        private Task ResumeAfterInsightsDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
       #endregion
    }
```

I found the following exception in logs and it occurs right after calling the constructor of RootDialog class:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stringToEscape
   at System.Uri.EscapeDataString(String stringToEscape)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisRequest.BuildUri(ILuisModel model)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisService.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.ILuisService.BuildUri(LuisRequest luisRequest)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Extensions.<QueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<MessageReceived>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringEventLoop`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.EventLoopDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SetAmbientThreadCulture.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.QueueDrainingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CustomerInsights.MessagesController.<Post>d__0.MoveNext()
```

This code is working fine on emulator and web chat channels but thrown an exception only on CORTANA channel. Appreciate to help me out.

Comment: can you post more code as to where you have used "stringToEscape" variable.

Comment: I suspect the userInput string is not being passed down to the child dialog, If you want to pass the message to the child dialog "customerInsightsDialog" then there are 2 ways to do this: 1st way is to pass the message inside the constructor of the child dialog: context.Call(customerInsightsDialog(stringInput), SomeResumeAfter), 2nd way is to use context.Forward: context.Forward(customerInsightsDialog, this.ResumeAftercustomerInsightsDialogEnded, context.MakeMessage(), CancellationToken.None);

Comment: stringToEscape is being called internally by Bot Framework. Actually Its not calling the Intent methods at all if I remove the "context.call" method from the dialog then still get the same issue.

Comment: Maybe its not calling the LUIS service at all, Try using the LuisModel attribute on the top of your dialog instead putting that inside of a static constructor. [LuisModel(ConstantResources.LUISModel, ConstantResources.LUISSubscriptionKey, LuisApiVersion.V2)]

Comment: I have tried by both ways from my static function and by using these attributes. It does not make any difference.

Comment: can you override the DispatchToIntentHandler() method, and put a breakpoint there and check. protected void override DispatchToIntentHandler()

Comment: Thanks Kunal I have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by modifying the existing code of class "MessagesController" as follows:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.Text))
                     {
                          var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

                          Activity reply = activity.CreateReply();
                          reply.Text = string.Format(Resources.WELCOME_MESSAGE, Constants.UserInfo.FullName);
                          reply.Speak = SSMLHelper.Speak(string.Format(Resources.WELCOME_MESSAGE, Constants.UserInfo.FullName));
                          reply.InputHint = InputHints.ExpectingInput;

                          await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                     }
                 else
                    {
                          await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
                     }
            }
            else
            {
                await HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
```

Actually the "Text" property of "Activity" object was empty. So right now I am asking to user to input (via Speak) some text to proceed further.